# Why does git revert behave differently in these cases?

Tags: git, git-revert

Let's say I have **ProjectA** and **ProjectB** in which I have only one file called **test.txt** in both projects and tracking it with git. After the first commit, the content of the file in both projects look like below.

```
one
two
three
four
```

After second commit, the content of the file in both project looks like below.

```
one
2
three
four
```

For third commit, I change the content a bit different

**test.js** in **ProjectA** after third commit

```
one
2
3
four
```

**test.js** in **ProjectB** after third commit

```
one
2
three
4
```

Now my question is.. after third commit, when I try to revert the changes made in second commit using git revert like below..

`git revert secondCommitHashId`, git ends up in merge conflict in **ProjectA**, but git happily gives me vim editor mode to enter revert message in **ProjectB** to finish the revert operation without merge conflict.

Why does `git revert hashId` behave different in these cases?

Comment: "when I try to revert to second commit using git revert like below `git revert secondCommitHashId`" No. that command does not revert _to_ the second commit. It reverts the second commit _itself_. In other words, it says: make a new commit that reverses the difference between the first commit and the second commit, and applies the reversal to the last commit.

Comment: @matt that was actually what I wanted to mean. I've edited the text now to clarify a bit more

Comment: git will quite often flag it as a conflict if two files to merge changes lines next to each other, which they will for ProjectA. In ProjectB, there's one line between, and thus the git code doesn't flag this as a conflict.

Comment: So git decides to raise conflict depends on what changes on the next line? In other words, git only checks for the next line, not the line after the next line? Du må forklar meg dette over en kaffe @LasseV.Karlsen :)

Answer (score 1):

#### What is `git revert`

`git revert` is a request to make a new commit on the current branch, whose parent will be the current HEAD commit. The new commit is created using *merge logic* (which I explain pretty extensively in [this article](https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/)). But the new commit is not, itself, a merge commit; that is, it only has one parent.

The commit is created as follows:

1. Look at the `diff` between (a) the commit we are being asked to revert and (b) the parent of that commit. In other words, think about how we would go backwards from the commit to be reverted to the state that preceded it.
2. Look also at the `diff` between (a) the commit we are being asked to revert and (c) the commit where we are now (aka HEAD).
3. Create a commit that enacts *both* of those diffs, simultaneously, on (a) the commit we are being asked to revert, and append it to the current branch.

So in this little story of yours, with just three commits, (a) is the second commit, (b) is the first commit, and (c) is the third commit. You are asking Git to make a commit that enacts the diff from the second commit to the first commit and from the second commit to the third commit, simultaneously.

But Git can't do that; it has reached an *aporia*, a place where it can go no further on its own. By an unfortunate turn of phrase, this situation is called a *merge conflict*.

Now let's look at why that is.

#### Examine the "conflict"

When Git runs into this situation, it makes, in your working tree, a special conflict file that describes the problem. If you look at that conflict file, especially if you have your merge conflicts [configured](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergeconflictStyle) to use `diff3` formatting, the answer to your question is clear.

This is what the conflicted file looks like (I've changed some names to make things clearer):

```
one
<<<<<<< third commit
2
3
||||||| second commit
2
three
=======
two
three
>>>>>>> first commit
four
```

Let's read this together. In the middle, between `|||` and `===`, is the second commit, with `2 three`. Above that is where we are now, HEAD, the third commit, with `2 3`. Below it is the first commit, with `two three`.

Now, recall that what reverting the second commit means in this situation is: enact *both* the reversal of the second commit back to the first commit, *and* the change from the second commit to the third commit, *simultaneously.*

So Git needs to find a way to go from `2 three` to *both* `2 3` *and* `two three` simultaneously. But there is no such way! Thus Git doesn't know what to do, and there is a conflict.

#### The hunk

The only surprise here, perhaps, is that the third line is part of the problematic hunk. Why doesn't Git think about *just* the second line, alone? It's because Git *never* does that. There's no such thing, in Git's mind, as a one-line hunk. It always considers the context. So if two consecutive lines differ for one of the diffs under consideration, they are *both* part of the hunk we are trying to resolve.

#### What about your second example?

Now let's talk about why the same issue doesn't arise for your second example. In your second example, the third line does *not* change between the second and the third commits. In fact, in your second example, neither the first line, nor the second line, nor the third line changes between the second and the third commits.

So the goal of the revert, with respect to the first three lines of the file, is to enact the reverse-change from (a) `one 2 three` to (b) `one two three`, on the one hand, and from (a) `one 2 three` to (c) `one 2 three`, on the other. But that's easy, because the second diff is *no diff at all!* The contribution of the second diff is *nothing!* So the first diff is the *only* thing we have to do in this part of the file, and we can do it.

Now let's consider the rest of the file. Let's take the third and fourth lines. (Remember, there are no one-line hunks.) Here, we enact a reverse change from (a) `three four` back to (b) `three four`, together with a change from (a) `three four` to (c) `three 4`. Well, in this case, the *first* diff is no diff at all and makes no contribution. So the only thing we have to do is the change from `three four` to `three 4`, and we can do it.

Thus there are no issues with the second example, and Git creates the new commit without any complaint.

Answer (score 1):

A `git revert` is a merge operation. You have this history:

```
1--2--3
```

and you ask for

```
git revert 2
```

The base version is the project state at `2`, "our" version is the state at `3`, and "their" version (which is being merged in) is `1`. In other words, the changes from `2` to `1` and from `2` to `3` are merged.

In both your examples, the change from `2` to `1` replaces the text `2` in line 2 by the word `two` (bad coincidences of 2s, unfortunately). The differences is in the projects: In Project A, the change from `2` to `3` changes the 3rd line, while in Project B, the change from `2` to `3` changes the 4th line.

In the former case, the diverging changes modify adjacent lines. Git flags this as a conflict.

In the latter case, there is an unmodified line (the third line) between the diverging changes. Here Git is able to separate the changes clearly and can resolve the merge.